# how to configure angular to work remotely with django APIs?

Tags: django, angular

I am running a web application, front-end with angular and back-end with  django. the thing is: These two frameworks are not running on the same server. how can I configure angular to work remotely with APIs? (I have tested the APIs, and they are just fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after hours of debugging I finally found it.

## `FIRST`

Create a file named `proxy.conf.json` in `/src` folder and fill it with this json:

```
   {
      "/api": {
        "target": "http://test.com/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "info"
      }
    }
```

This line is ESSENTIAL:
`"changeOrigin": true,`

## `THEN`

Edit the angular.json file.In the `projects` section, find `architect` and append this line to `options`section:
`"proxyConfig":"src/proxy.conf.json"`. 
So it should look like this:

```
    .
    .
    .
      "options": {
                    "browserTarget": "some-name:build",
                    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
                  },
    .
    .
    .
```

`NOTE1` Trailing comma is not allowed in JSON.
`NOTE2` Loglevel gives you more information.
`NOTE3` Thanks to Haifeng for his guide.

Comment: This shouldn’t be necessary. You should just be able to call the host:port or domain name if your Django app directly from angular if you have cors set up in Django

Answer (score 1):

Check setup proxy for your project from [Proxying to a backend server](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Basically you need to create a proxy.conf.json file and have settings like:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then you can define your backend hostname, port and available APIs and other settings.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I’ve run ~10 angular / Django projects and never needed this